# Assign multiple values to a label in shiny input

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

In my Shiny ui input, I have two networks that are assigned values.  When the user selects New York, the `network$id` used in the `server.R` will change to 1, and when the user selects Los Angeles, the `network$id` will change to 2. This is the basic functionality of `selectInput`

```
  selectInput("networkid", "Network:",
              c("New York" =  1,
                "Los Angeles" =2))
```

If I wanted to store another variable(s) in input, how would I do this without creating another input? For example, if I wanted to store timezone, how would I design the input so that "New York" = "EST" , "Los Angeles" = "PST", and that this variable is called `networktz` ?

Comment: Within server, this might work: `networktz <- reactive({ req(input$networkid); c("New York"="EST", "Los Angeles"="PST")[input$networkid]; })`, referenced elsewhere as `networktz()`. Otherwise, you will need to update your question with a MWE.

Comment: You should clarify why you need this functionality. It looks to me you are trying to put some server logic and data structure to the UI side. Since each network already has an ID associated, your server can maintain a lookup list for other network properties. Everytime the `input$networkid` changes, the server will do the heavy lift to search for the timezone.